# What is the closest complete native library to three.js?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, three.js

I am looking for the best native library that is similar to three.js in its structure and simplicity but is also extensible enough to support glsl shaders.

### Requirements:

- Open Source or very well documented for possible extension/enhancement
- Allows commercial derivatives/use
- Can either be wrapped in a physics library or easily paired with one.
- Fast enough to support modern game graphics.
- OpenGL or Mantle based. (I don't want to be stuck with windows.)
- Windows support
- Supports a system similar to three.js local/world coordinate system.
- Raycasting support for doing collision detection.

### Huge Bonus:

- Supports Linux and OSX as well as windows.

I am looking for the closest match to Three.js as possible that is written in C++ similar to  [three.cpp](https://github.com/jdduke/three_cpp) but has completed functionality and is less beta/alpha status.

Comment: Why not simply use OpenGL?

Comment: Check [Magnum](http://mosra.cz/blog/article.php?a=22-introducing-magnum-a-multiplatform-2d-3d-graphics-engine)

Comment: @Vallentin why not use asm directly, why use cross-platform wrappers at all?

Comment: @OneOfOne Wrapper? What? Are you sure you know what OpenGL is.

Comment: I know what opengl is, however there's are all kinds of different headers to use on different platforms and using a library simplifies having to write 1000s of lines of code by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Magnum ?

http://mosra.cz/blog/download-magnum.php

Supported platforms

Graphics APIs:

```
OpenGL 2.1 through 4.4, core profile functionality and modern extensions
OpenGL ES 2.0, 3.0 and extensions to match desktop OpenGL functionality
WebGL 1.0 and extensions to match desktop OpenGL functionality
```

Platforms:

```
Linux and embedded Linux (natively using GLX/EGL and Xlib or through GLUT or SDL2 toolkit)
Windows (through GLUT or SDL2 toolkit)
OS X (through SDL2 toolkit, thanks to Miguel Martin)
Google Chrome (through Native Client, both newlib and glibc toolchains are supported)
HTML5/JavaScript (through Emscripten)
```

Comment: This looks pretty excellent for my core library. It seems to be even more compatible than I expected to be possible and remains lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

Threejs actually does support glsl shaders. You can use [THREE.ShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) class to create your own shader then pass your vertexShader and fragmentShader to it.

Another option is to program directly in WebGL. ThreeJS is built on top of WebGL. The only reason why I decided to use ThreeJS was to avoid writing glsl shaders since WebGL doesn't have materials and forces you to write your own glsl shaders, so if that's what you want you could go directly to WebGL. WebGL is more low level than Threejs.

If you don't like javascript, then you could use [JogAmp's Ardor3D](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) which is in Java. It's a 3D scenegraph renderer just like Threejs but in Java.

All of the above options have super fast game quality rendering performance.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I know that three has shaders but I wanted to ensure whatever library I moved to maintained that ability and possibly had basic shaders built in.

Comment: I do really like the ability to write in java though. I just don't trust code safety if I release something I intend to remain secure. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned you wanted it to be in C++ in your original question. In that case, use http://www.openscenegraph.org/ It's in C++ and it has everything you need. I used it before I switched to Ardor3D because I preferred Java. You know, with Java you don't need to worry about security if you are developing a stand-alone application. Only online applets and webstart can cause security problems.

Comment: The "official" Ardor3D is dead, you should rather mention JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation. If you like Javascript and WebGL, you should try GooEngine too.